# Cucumber feature file Parallel execution is possible?

Tags: parallel-processing, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, mobile-devices

We are running Automation scripts for Mobile devices with Android, and IOS.

We are trying to run two feature files for two Android devices(One Plus and Samsung S10).

Initially scripts are ran on both the devices but when the first Feature file execution is stopped then automatically the execution process on Second device also stopped.

Appium version - 1.16.0

We tried changing the order of the devices also like Running Feature file of Samsung s10 first and One Plus later and changed by initiating the execution of feature file of OnePlus device first and Samsung S10 next.

In both the cases the same happened when execution of first initiated is ended the other process is stopped suddenly without any error

We are retrieving the capabilities of the devices from database.

Running these scripts on Mac machine

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that switching devices in the middle of a run is probably not a good idea

So to start I'd suggest creating a project folder for each device you are trying to test. Then run cucumber in one folder to test the first device and then a second folder to test the second.

Once you have that working then you can think about how to run both things at the same time, without having multiple project folders on your machine. There are lots of ways to do this

- setup a dedicated CI machine
- use a CI service like CircleCI
  ...

The key idea here is to parallize using multiple Cucumber instances rather than a single cucumber instance.